# Find changed rows by DateModified column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple tables (let's say `Table2`, `Table3`, `Table4`) and each of them has a `DateModified` column. What's the best way to update `Table1` to have the latest `DateModified` from `Table2`, `Table3`, `Table4` that's different then the current `DateModified` in `Table1`?

Here's my current query and it works fine, but it's slow on large tables (say 2.000.000 rows)

```
update
    t1
set
    IsChanged = 1,
    DateModified = isnull((
        select
            max(v)
        from
            (values (t2.DateModified), (t3.DateModified), (t4.DateModified)) as value (v)
    ), '1900-01-01')
from
    Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t2.id_Table1 = t1.id_Table1
    inner join Table3 t3 on t3.id_Table2 = t2.id_table2
    inner join Table4 t4 on t4.id_Table3 = t2.id_table3
where
    isnull(t1.DateModified, '1900-01-01') <> isnull((
        select
            max(v)
        from
            (values (t2.DateModified), (t3.DateModified), (t4.DateModified)) as value (v)
    ), '1900-01-01')
```

Comment: Using CASE WHEN to get the highest DateModified MIGHT be faster than the max.

Comment: It would probably make sense to create a trigger that will update Table1 whenever is necessary, thus eliminitating the need for this complex query altogether.

Comment: BTW are all the relationships here one-to-one? Otherwise I can imagine you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: yes, in the end they are one-to-one